# Simple linq select query not returning correct results

Tags: linq, select

When I run the following query in SQL Server Management Studio I get 132 rows of data. This is correct.

```
select *
from cyc.contac con 
where (con.note_turn is null) and 
      (con.cont_type <> '_') and 
      (con.cont_code <> 'D') and 
      (con.cont_type <> 'Q')
```

When I run the following Linq query from my code I get over 11000 records. This is not correct. I am wondering why my linq query is not constraining by the constraints in my where clause.

```
var query = from contac in context.CONTACs
            orderby contac.ID
            where (contac.note_turn == null) && 
                  (contac.cont_type != "_") && 
                  (contac.cont_code != "D") && 
                  (contac.cont_type != "Q")
            select contac;
```

Comment: see how your LINQ is translated to SQL. My guess is that the `== null` condition might not get translated to  `is null`

Comment: What SQL query is generated by that LINQ query?

Comment: $contac.note_turn == (System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])null && $contac.cont_type != "_" && $contac.cont_code != "D" && $contac.cont_type != "Q"

Comment: Just for fun, try your query in http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: Well, that was fun. linqpad seems to work fine but when I paste the query in Visual Studio and run my application I still get the same results. The only thing that linkpad changed was converting my contac.Note_turn == null to contac.note_turn == (DateTime?)null

Comment: What if you do `!contac.note_turn.HasValue`?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It seems that my WHERE clause was not the problem. It was what my function was returning. I was mistakenly returning my Entinty Framwork context, which returned the results of the entire table and not the results of the query. I was assumning that the framework would put my fesults in the EF context for me to retreive later. 

I quess that I have a lot more to learn about linq and the entity framework.

Thanks for all of the help. By showing me that there was nothing wrong with my query I was able to start looking in the right direction.

Comment: @BarrySnow, thanks for posting the comment.  Please re-post as an answer to make it clear you found a solution.  You can (and should) answer your own question when possible.